# How to simplify the series of $x + x^{-1} + (x + x^{-1})^{-1} + (x + x^{-1} + (x + x^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, continued-fractions

$$x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x} + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x}} +\cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x} + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x}} } + \cdots $$

How can this series be simplified? Consider me as a high school graduate.

Comment: As a high school graduate, what have you tried?

Comment: So $a_1=x$ and $a_n=1/(a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1})$.

Comment: a1 = x, then a2 = a1 + 1/a1, then a3 = a2 + 1/a2, then a4 = a3 + 1/a3 and so on...

Comment: So $f(x) = x+1/x$ and $t_n = f^{\circ n}(x)$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n$?

Comment: @mathreadler Looks more like $\lim f^{\circ n}(x)$ to me, but still doesn't converge ($f$ has no fixed point)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes you are right, the sum is not necessary just $n\to \infty$. But it can still help as it provides a $f$ to investigate.

Answer (score 4):

By setting $a_1=x$ and $a_N = \frac{1}{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{N-1}}$ we may easily see that there are quite a lot convergence issues. If $a_1+a_2+a_N\to L\neq 0$, then $a_N\to \frac{1}{L}$, contradicting the convergence of the series. On the other hand also $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_N\to 0$ leads to a contradiction, hence your series **cannot** be convergent.

Comment: And what if I've limited number of terms? Like I've to solve this for 10 terms. Actually, I couldn't create formula for this series.

Comment: @SarthakJoshi: that is an entirely different question, not involving a series but just a finite sum.

Comment: So, better to ask it in a separate question, or just look at the questions in the database asking for the behaviour of $b_{n+1}=b_n+\frac{1}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the nth partial sum. The series is divergent. Note that since $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$, $(a_{n+1})^2=(a_n)^2+2+(a_n)^{-2} >(a_n)^2+2$. Therefore, by induction, $(a_n)^2>2n$ for all $n>2$, thus $a_n>\sqrt{2n}$ which means the series is divergent.

Credits to http://www.math.umd.edu/highschool/mathcomp/2000sol2.html for the solution.

Note: The solution above only works for $x>0$. If $x<0$, notice that the partial sum $\mid a_n \mid$ is the same for $x$ and $-x$, so the series diverges for $x<0$ as well.